# Finding inverse of polynomial matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Consider a unimodular square polynomial matrix $A(x)$ with elements defined over the polynomial ring $F[x]$ with coefficients from a finite Galois field. By the unimodular property, we know that the matrix has determinant equal to non-zero element, which also means that the inverse matrix $A(x)^{-1}$ exists and its elements are defined over $F[x]$ as well.

Could someone point me at a suitable method / approach for finding the inverse matrix $A(x)^{-1}$? I know that one could easily find the inverse over the field of rational functions $F(x)$ (for example by using Gauss-Jordan elimination, or LU factorization with full pivoting) but I need to find the inverse matrix with elements defined over the polynomial ring $F[x]$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see why the determinant of $A(x)$ has to equal $\pm1$, or how this would follow from the unimodular property; a matrix with coefficients in $F[X]$ is unimodular if its determinant is a unit in $F[X]$, i.e. a nonzero element of $F$.

Comment: Also, if $A(X)$ is unimodular then it has an inverse in $F[X]$. So if by Gauss-Jordan elimination you find an inverse of $A(X)$ in $F(X)$, by uniqueness of the inverse it must be the inverse of $A(X)$ in $F[X]\subset F(X)$. That is to say, Gauss-Jordan elimination will give you the inverse matrix with elements defined over $F[X]$.

Comment: @servaes Thank you very much for the reasoning! You are absolutely correct, the statement about determinant equal to $\pm 1$ is not true indeed. I used Gauss-Jordan elimination method, as you suggested. If you add an answer to the thread, I would mark it as correct.

Comment: In any commutative ring $R$, a matrix $B\in M_n(R)$ has an inverse in $M_n(R)$ iff $\det(B) \in M^\times$. In that case $B^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(B)} \text{adj}(B)$ where $\text{adj}$ is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). Here depending on the determinant you should take $R = F[x]$ or $R = F(x)$ @Servaes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gauss-Jordan elimination of $A(x)$ yields a matrix in $F(x)$ that is inverse to $A(x)$. Because $A(x)$ is unimodular it has an inverse in $F[x]\subset F(x)$, so by uniqueness of the inverse, Gauss-Jordan elimination yields a matrix in $F[x]$.